# Apollo GraphQL pass object

Tags: graphql, apollo

In GraphQL, how do I pass an object instead of a string?

Take this code from Apollo's website as an example, with my minor change:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useLazyQuery } from '@apollo/client';

function DelayedQuery() {
  const [dog, setDog] = useState(null);
  const [getDog, { loading, data }] = useLazyQuery(GET_DOG_PHOTO);

  if (loading) return <p>Loading ...</p>;

  if (data && data.dog) {
    setDog(data.dog);
  }

  const myObject = {
    type: {
      favors: [
        tom: true,
        bill: false
      ]
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {dog && <img src={dog.displayImage} />}
      <button onClick={() => getDog({ variables: { theObject: myObject } })}>
        Click me!
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I believe React is trying to parse the object into a string, but (as the error message explains) `JSON.stringify cannot serialize cyclic structures`.

What do I do?

Comment: why do you want to do this? does the grahphql schema allow JSON as the variable? check your type definitions

Comment: also setting state with `useState` with your apollo data is unnecessary, the state is already stored in `data`

Comment: @azium, I think the error I am getting happens before React passes the data to the GraphQL. So whether or not the schema accepts JSON is (at this stage) irrelevant. As for your other comment - I am using the code on Apollo's website as example. https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/queries/#executing-queries-manually

Comment: @azium and I need to pass the object to GraphQL to perform recaptcha verification with Firebase. But that is also beside the point.

Comment: interesting. is this only happening in lazy query? what about a normal `useQuery` ?

Comment: @azium, I haven't tried a `useQuery` because I need this to run on button click, but I can imagine the result will be the same.

Comment: schema can be relevant ... variables can be differently processed ... prepare working, editable [example] os codesandbox ... just for proof it is irrelevant ;)